Bounding a ratio of parametrized sums, uniformly
Let $\gamma_{p}\ge0$ be a sequence such that $\sum_{p\ge2}\gamma_p^2p^k<\infty$ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Define: $C_k(s)=\sum_{p\ge2}\gamma_p^2s^pp^k$ for $s\in\left(0,1\right]$. I want to show that $$\frac{C_{3}\left(s\right)}{C_{2}\left(s\right)}=\frac{\sum_{p\ge2}\gamma_{p}^{2}s^{p}p^{3}}{\sum_{p\ge2}\gamma_{p}^{2}s^{p}p^{2}}$$
can be bounded uniformly (same bound for every $s$). Maybe more generally, that $\frac{C_{k_{1}}\left(s\right)}{C_{k_{2}}\left(s\right)}$  can be bounded uniformly (the bound only depends on $k_1,k_2$). I wonder if I need to suppose something stronger about $\gamma_p$ (maybe exponentially decaying).
I tried to use methods suggested in a question I asked before that touched a similar probelm without much of success. It seems like $C_k(s)$, normailzed, are convex combinations of unbounded functions, but the fact that the coefficients decay fast, make the expected value somewhat bounded. And as $s$ gets smaller, the expected value is as well of course. I just can't find an arguement for the ratio.

ok got it, for $s\rightarrow0$ we divide everything by $s^2$ and see that the limit is finite. So this is a continuous function on a compact interval
